# How to make a Vue 3 object property reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

How can I make an object property `reactive`?

When I run the code below, the imported `visible` doesn't change to `true`.

**Component that imports the object:**

```html
<template>
    <div class="context">
        <span v-if="visible"> test </span>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import { ContextManager } from "./utils.js";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
    name: "context",
    setup() {
        const visible = ref(ContextManager.visible);

        return { visible };
    }
};
</script>
```

**Other component that adds data to the object:**

```js
const openContext = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ContextManager.add({
        el: e.target,
        items: contextItems
    },e );
};
```

**ContextManager object:**

```js
import { reactive } from "vue";

export const ContextManager = reactive({
    context: null,
    visible: false,
    add(context, e) {
        this.visible = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object's properties are not refs, so when you extract the `visible` property, there's no connection remaining to the original object, because it's just a vanilla boolean.

The [`toRef`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref) api method is provided for this purpose, to maintain this connection:

> Can be used to create a ref for a property on a source reactive object. The ref can then be passed around, retaining the reactive connection to its source property.

Import the `toRef` method and use it like:

```js
import { toRef } from 'vue'
```

```
const visible = toRef(ContextManager, 'visible');
```